# How to open a UNC path in a new browser in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I meet a problem with navigateurl in silverlight to a UNC Path folder. I have a silverlight5 app. the requirement : opening a UNC Path folder in silverlight.

Question 1: My codes:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(@"\\10.10.0.26"),"_blank");
```

I added site to trust site in IE. It worked fine in IE, but in firefox the url becomes "http://mydomainname.com.cn/\172.16.6.199".It doesn't forward UNC Path.

Question 2: My codes:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(@"\\10.10.0.26\software"),"_blank");
```

It doesn't work. It hasn't any action. If i input "\10.10.0.26\software" on IE URL Address, it worked fine.

PS: Have other good way to solve my problem?